# Run Python Code during a click event in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm new to Flask. I want to click the button in my inputs.html file to do two tasks, namely to submit form data to database (which is functioning correctly now) and to run another function which does some calculations based on the inputs just submitted to the database.

inputs.html file has following code

```
  <form action = "{{ url_for('addrec') }}" method = "POST">
     <h3>Inputs</h3>

     Number of Students<br>
     <input type = "text" name = "stu" /></br>

     Number of Tasks<br>
     <input type = "text" name = "tasks" /><br>

     <input type = "submit" value = "Submit" onsubmit="{{ url_for('my_link')}}"/>
     <br>

  </form>
```

In the app.py I have the following code to handle the form data

```
@app.route('/addrec',methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def addrec():
  if request.method == 'POST':
   try:
     students = request.form['stu']
     tasks = request.form['tasks']

     with sql.connect("database.db") as con:
        cur = con.cursor()

        cur.execute("INSERT INTO inputs (students,tasks) 
         VALUES (?,?)",(students,tasks))

        con.commit()
        msg = "Record successfully added"
   except:
     con.rollback()
     msg = "error in insert operation"

   finally:
     return render_template("result.html",msg = msg)

@app.route('/my_link')
def my_link():
   print 'My Link Works!'
```

However, when I click the button form details added to the database correctly. But I do not see message "My Link Works" in debugger. Does this implies that I cannot do both tasks (insert records to database and run another function) when I click the button?

Is there a way to achieve this?

Please help.

Comment: Why not just call the second function from the first?

Comment: Hi, Sorry I'm not clear what do you mean?

Comment: You'd have to set `onsubmit` on the form, not an input element, and it should be a function not a string.

Comment: @Blurp Pretty sure that would trigger `my_link` and not `addrec`. So I'm not very sure what the end result should look like.

Comment: @Ann Instead of having a `my_link` function that the user has to trigger, just run whatever function that needs to run right after the database insert.

Comment: I think the handler would be triggered _and_ the form would be submitted. Your suggestion is better: there should probably be a single endpoint for this form.

Comment: @tyteen4a03 I like your suggestion. I actually added it as another function because I don't know how to call a function inside another function

Comment: `con.rollback()` and `render_template("result.html",msg = msg)` *is* calling another function ;)

Comment: `onsubmit` is for *JavaScript* event functions, which run on the client. The server doesn't see that, it only sees the HTTP POST request, which gets routed to the `/addrec` route. If you want to do other operations on the server, you need to do that in response to the request that the server sees.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. It makes sense. However, I have only the  <form action = "{{ url_for('addrec') }}" method = "POST"> in my inputs.html file. Can I pass another route in the same form so that I can call another function?

Comment: The only way you could do something like that would be to add on `onsubmit` handler to the `<form>` and then do an AJAX request from the handler (note: don't do this). But it would be much easier to just have `addrec` save the record _and_ do the calculations.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.